# pointer to variable holding an address

Tags: c, pointers, addressing

I'm trying to compute a CRC32 for the application code on an 8052 embedded platform.

The following is given as a guide to calculating the CRC :

```
void TestChecksum()
{
     unsigned short calc = 0;

     /* Run the checksum algorithm */
     calc = slow_crc16(0, (unsigned char *) ChecksumStart, (ChecksumEnd - ChecksumStart+1));

     /* Rotate out the answer */
     unsigned char zeros[2] = {0, 0};
     calc = slow_crc16(calc, zeros, 2);

     etc...
}
```

where

```
unsigned short slow_crc16(unsinged short sum, unsigned char *p, unsigned int len)
{
     while (len--)
     {
         int i;
         unsigned char byte = *(p++);

         for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
         {
          etc...
         }
}
```

The problem with the example is that the pointer automatically points to XData whereas I'm after CODE. I know the address of the code from which I would like to calculate the CRC, say 0x2000 to 0x2FFF.

Is it possible to define a pointer as, say:

```
uint8_t __code *Ptr;
```

And pass in an address, the 0x2000, as a uint32 to the CRC function ?

Basically I can't work out how to get a pointer to point to an address which is actually stored as a variable.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm not sure this is even possible.

Comment: If you know the starting address, just set the pointer to that value: Ptr = 0x2000;

Answer (score 0):

A pointer *is* an integer; it just has a special type to stop it getting mixed up with other pointers (or numbers).

On many architectures you can convert pointers to numbers and back again without loosing anything:

```
char *ptr = (char *)0x2000;
int address = (int)ptr;
```

[This doesn't work on architectures where the pointer's "integer" is a different size to an ordinary `int` "integer". There are a few other exotic cases you almost certainly don't care about also.]

In fact, the only way to get a pointer to do anything other than "be an integer" is to dereference it:

```
char c = *ptr;
```

or, the exact same thing using array notation:

```
char c = ptr[0];
```

or, only if `ptr` is a pointer to a `struct` type:

```
int v = ptr->value;
```

In all those cases, it uses the pointer as address, and fetches the referenced data from memory.

Finally, you can *get* a pointer to a variable using the "address-of" operator (a.k.a "reference" operator):

```
char c = 'Z';
char *ptr = &c;
```